# Error in setting up laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to set up a relationship in Laravel using the eloquent relationship model, it looks like the one below

```
users
     id 
     email

projects 
     id
     name

user_projects
     user_id
     project_id
     role
```

I want to be able to query the projects that the user is a part of irrespective of the role that he has. To do this, I used the following in my user model.

```
  class User extends Model {

    public function allProjects() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProjectRoles', 'user_projects', 'user_id', 'project_id');

    }
}
```

But because of this I get an error in my code

```
 Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user_projects' (SQL: select `user_projects`.*, `user_projects`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `user_projects`.`project_id` as `pivot_project_id` from `user_projects` inner join `user_projects` on `user_projects`.`id` = `user_projects`.`project_id` where `user_projects`.`user_id` = 2)
```

I am not sure how to create the join query in the relationships in order to do it. Any help would be appreciated. I went through the eloquent docs but wasn't able to get the result even though the examples there do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `belongsToMany` relationship is related to the wrong Model. Generally you don't have a model for your pivot table, but even if you do, your `belongsToMany` relationship doesn't use it. Your `User` model should be related to your `Project` model.

You should use this:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function allProjects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'user_projects', 'user_id', 'project_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks man, that did work, will it be possible to explain it in a little bit more detail ?

Comment: @Bazinga777 You may want to take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). If there are still questions, please ask.

Comment: It really is magical to me right now, but I am gonna go through the docs and videos on laracast again. Thanks Mate